# Optimizing gsutil download for folder subset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have a set of files stored in a Google Cloud bucket - 100k files which total 1 TB. I need a way to efficiently download varying file subsets from the bucket.

There is a way with passing the list of desired files to `gsutil`: `python generate_filenames.py | gsutil -m cp -I .` but it's very slow for my scenario (about 2 MB/sec).

Alternatively, I noticed that if a wildcard pattern is used - `gsutil -m cp gs://bucketname/folderpath/* .` - the download is about 10 times as fast. I could download all the files and then delete the undesired ones but it would still be inefficient if the set of files is small.

Is there any way to utilize `gsutil` to download only the specified list of files but still have a speed better than 2 MB/sec?

Answer (score 1):

Try randomizing the order of the files in your input list. GCS stores files on shards distributed by object key, so files that are *lexically similar* are likely to be stored on the same shard. If you are trying to pull a large number of small files from a single shard, it can cause performance to suffer. Depending on the naming convention for your files, you may be limited in what you can achieve with this strategy. See docs on [using a naming convention that distributes load evenly across key ranges](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention).

Other than that, there a number of variables at play which could affect performance: your internet connection, your GCS storage class, your machine, etc. Google Cloud provides a tool called [**`perfdiag`**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/perfdiag) that can help diagnose this kind of issue.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Unfortunately, randomizing the order of the filenames passed to `gsutil -m cp -I` didn't improve the speed for me (though it did introduce randomness to the opening filename symbols). Do you possibly know why could the download with wildcards be so notably faster than passing the filenames one by one?

Comment: I was hoping `gsutil` was being clever and randomizing the wildcard expansion. But I don't know.